# Manipulating character vectors: removing and adding quotes, adding strings

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have `vector_1`, which I want to manipulate with code so that `vector_2` and `vector_3` are generated automatically.

```
# What I have
> vector_1 <- c("Group_A", "Group_B", "Group_C", "Group_D")
> vector_1
[1] "Group_A" "Group_B" "Group_C" "Group_D"
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
# What I want to achieve by manipulating vector_1: 
vector_2 = c("Group_A, Group_B, Group_C, Group_D")
vector_3 = c(" ", "Group_A" = 3, "Group_B" = 3, "Group_C" = 3, "Group_D" = 3))
```

I assume `noquote()` is a starting point, but then I get stuck.

```
> vector_x <- noquote(vector_1)
> vector_x
[1] Group_A Group_B Group_C Group_D
# Here I'm stuck...
```

Base R would do, but I prefer to work in the tidyverse, with or without pipes.

--- Edit ---

Following up Sotos' question in the comments:

I want to use `vector_3` as a header in `kableExtra`.
Instead of writing...

```
kbl(
[hidden code] %>%
add_header_above(c(" ", "Group_A"=3, "Group_B"=3, "Group_C"=3, "Group_D"=3)) %>%
[more_code]
)
```

I haven't been able to make a reproducible example that works outside of PDF. Here's a link to `add_header_above()`:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.3.4/topics/add_header_above

Comment: `vector_2 <- paste0(vector_1, collapse = ", ")`

Comment: Can you explain vector_3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toString` for `vector_2`, and `setNames` for `vector_3`:

```r
toString(vector_1)
# [1] "Group_A, Group_B, Group_C, Group_D"

c(" ", setNames(rep(3, 4), vector_1))
#        Group_A Group_B Group_C Group_D 
#    " "     "3"     "3"     "3"     "3"
```

Comment: Both this and the answer by zx8754 answer my question. I have also tested them within kableExtra and they seem to do the trick when applied to develop a table and add_headers_above() with kableExtra.

Answer (score 2):

vector_2:

```
paste(vector_1, collapse = ", ")
# [1] "Group_A, Group_B, Group_C, Group_D"
```

And vector_3:

```
setNames(c(" ", rep(3, length(vector_1))), c("", vector_1))
#     Group_A Group_B Group_C Group_D 
# " "     "3"     "3"     "3"     "3"
```

Comment: Works just as well as Maël's answer.